# "npm install" does not create node_modules directory or if exists does not copy .node file

Tags: node.js, npm

```
package.json

{
  "name" : "abcjs"
  "description" : "Test project"
  "keywords": ["database", "db"],
  "version" : "0.1.0",

  "main": "./abc.js"
}
```

this uses `binding.gyp` in the current directory and compiles the project and `./build/Release/abc.node` gets created.

But `node_modules` sub-directory does not get created, or `abc.node` does not get copied to the `node_modules` directory.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks,
-P. Venkatraman.

Answer (score 1):

You need a "dependencies" option in the **package.json** file, such as the following:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "bignumber.js": "1.4.0",
    "readable-stream": "~1.1.13",
    "require-all": "0.0.8"
  },
```

These dependencies are created in the **node_modules** sub-folder.

Comment: I have a dependencies list, but for some reason **npm install** still does NOT create a node_modules directory, and consequently obviously does not install the packages that I need there.  Any ideas?

Comment: @CtheGood - have the same situation. I just switched to npm v 3.7.5.... and the node_modules dir is not being created now.  What version are you using?